# When data is processed in the .done() function, how do I remove the beforesend() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jquery because it's widely used in my current company. I'm having trouble with the following code. I can add the beforesend() function when the form is submitted with the message 'submitting,' but I can't remove it when the data is processed in the .done() function. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
   <!-- post form data -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".startup_form").on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                let formData = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "bot/company_crawler.php",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    encode: true,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#submitBtn").attr('disabled','disabled');
                        $("#loading").removeClass('hide');
                        $("#loading").addClass('show');
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $("#submitBtn").removeAttr('disabled');
                    $("#loading").addClass('hide');
                    $("#loading").removeClass('show');
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- ./post form data -->
```

Comment: The process is:  `beforeSend` -> `send` -> `done`.   There's no way to remove the beforeSend from the done handler because it's already been sent.   It's not clear exactly what you're asking.  Your question title asks about the function/callback itself, but the question appears to be asking about what happens *in* the function/callback.

Comment: what do you mean by can't remove it? What issue are you facing?

Comment: I want to remove the $('#loading) div when data is processed. I have tried but it's not working in the .done() function:

```$("#loading").addClass('hide');
$("#loading").removeClass('show');```

Comment: To clarify more, I want to remove the #loading div when data is saved to the database and there's a 200 success message in the callback.

Comment: First: check that `.done` is firing and that `#loading` exists by adding `console.log($("#loading").length)` and making sure it's == 1 .  Assuming it is and there is, then the issue will likely be with `$("#loading").addClass('hide');` - do you have a css definition for ".hide"?     What is it?  If you call `$("#loading").addClass('hide');` outside the `.done` does it work?   Please include the definition of `.hide`.

Comment: .hide has following css properties:

```.hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .show {
            display: inline;
        }```

on putting, ```$("#loading").addClass('hide');``` outside the ```.done``` it works.